# Upgrade wheels on '02 Honda Accord

Tags: honda, wheels, accord

I have a 2002 Honda Accord EX Sedan with manual transmission. I need to replace my tires, but was thinking about upgrading rims from 15" to 16". Is this possible on my car?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original equipment (OE) are 15" (as you stated). If you look at [this TireRack.com](https://www.tirerack.com/wheels/results.jsp?autoMake=Honda&autoModel=Accord+Sedan+EX+V6&autoYear=2002&autoModClar=&package=false) page, you'll see they have a selection of wheels ranging from your OE 15" up to 18". As long as you have the correct backspacing on the wheels, you shouldn't have an issue. Sites like TireRack and [DiscountTire.com](http://www.discounttiredirect.com/direct/assignWheelVehicle.do?yr=2002&mk=HONDA&selectedModel=ACCORD&vid=007182) (and others) can help you find wheels which will fit your vehicle. Moving up in size (ie: 15" to 16") is a lot easier than trying to go down in size. Really, you shouldn't have any issues.

There is one thing to check when you move to a different tire size. Check the *rotations per mile* (or RPM) of the tire and keep it about the same as the OE tires (+/- 1-2% of original). This will ensure your speedometer won't be too wonky when you get your new tires on the car.

Comment: So, if a newer model Accord uses 16", do you think the backspacing would still be the same? I'd be able to just use those? Also, good point about the RPM - hadn't thought of that.

Comment: @joshmax - On the new Accord, more than likely, but you never know. It's best to work with either the online calculator or with your retailer to ensure the backspacing is correct. Either way should get you the correct fit. You shouldn't have to worry about the fitment around the brake caliper or rotor as going larger in diameter means more room. If the backspacing is too far inboard, you can cause other issues with wheel arches and fenders.